# Arranging Fenceposts

Tags: code-golf, combinatorics

If you want to build a fence and have different length boards available, there are many different ways to set up your posts. So, given a minimum and maximum board length, a number of boards, and the total length, count how many ways you can arrange them.

**Input**

Input is four positive integers:

- **min:** The smallest board usable. Will be `>0`.
- **max:** The largest board available. Will be `>min`.
- **count:** Number of boards to use. Will be `>0`.
- **length:** Total length of the fence. For a valid fence, this should be `>=min*count` and `<=max*count`

Individual boards can be any *integer* length between `min` and `max` (inclusive).

**Output**

Output a single number representing the number of ways you can arrange the fence.

**Examples**

For input (in order listed above) `2 3 4 10`, you can arrange the boards six ways:

```
2233
2323
2332
3223
3232
3322
```

So the output is `6`. If your input was `1 3 4 6`, the output is `10`, since there are ten ways to do it:

```
1113   1212
1131   1221
1311   2112
3111   2121
1122   2211

Input          Output
5 10 6 45      4332
1 100 6 302    1204782674
27 53 8 315    4899086560
1 10 11 70     2570003777 
1 6 15 47      20114111295
4 8 150 600    1              // all boards length 4
1 10 100 80    0              // invalid, you can't put 100 boards in 80 length
```

Of course, there's a naive method to do this:

```java
long f(int min, int max, int count, int length){
    if(count==1)
        return 1;
    long num = 0;
    for(int i=min;i<=max;i++){
        int goal = length - i;
        if(goal <= max*(count-1) && goal >= min*(count-1)){
            num += f(min,max,count-1,goal);
        }
    }
    return num;
}
```

**Rules**

The algorithm given above works fine for small inputs, but it can easily overflow the `long` with larger inputs. Even with arbitrary-length numbers, it's incredibly inefficient. I believe it's `O((max-min+1)^count)`.

To be considered valid for this challenge, you should be able to compute input `1 10 100 700` in under one hour on my i7. Given a more efficient algorithm than the one above, this should not be a problem. I will test any entries I believe may come close to the limit. If your algorithm takes more than a few minutes to run, you should use a freely available language (on linux) to facilitate testing.

Code may take the form of a complete program or function, with input/output as any of the [standard methods](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1326/14215). Shortest code in bytes wins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Ruby: <s>106</s> <s>98</s> 93 bytes

*Update:* Changed cache key type from strings to arrays. (**-5**)

*Update:*  Storing the initial condition in the cache payed out quite well. (**-8**)
However, it increases the runtime for the test case to roughly 2 seconds.

I simply use memoization. I guess it can be further golfed as my Ruby skills are far from perfect.

```
@m={[0,0]=>1}
def f(l,u,c,s)
  @m[[c,s]]||=s<0?0:(l..u).map{|x|f(l,u,c-1,s-x)}.reduce(:+)
end
```

Note that it runs for only one test case at a time, since I don't cache the min and max values (`l` and `u`, respectively). Here is my output for `1 10 100 700`:

```
121130639107583774681451741625922964085713989291260198434849317132762403014516376282321342995

real    0m0.316s
user    0m0.312s
sys     0m0.004s
```

Comment: Yes, that's the correct output.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 55 [bytes](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)

```apl
⎕CY'dfns'
{0::0⋄⍺⊃⍵{+big⌿↑(⍳1+¯1⊥⍺)⌽¨⊂0,⍣(⊢/⍺)⊢⍵}⍣⍺⍺⊢1}
```

[Try it online! (without big, so fast but inaccurate)](https://tio.run/##VVAxT8JgEN2/X3EbEDTctf3awsoik4m4OFahaFJaIzXREBY1DJUSHfwDGBM3BuNiYkz4KfdH8NoC1hu@3L337r3L510G@71bL4gGa56/dA55@oRZ1z6p9PxwVFFjbLWQHx84/eLkntPPcZ1nPzx9rnL6QfXVkjh5E7LGs@/VOyd3uMfpa5WTRSNHk4XsTATKDDKPBU3WvsRwOhfD1dIULwnsHrXlPT7odNdxfxSLYDy8CGHo3cBZdB3GEPTDQXwOQoA4gpy0haqFwK/BZmOiMgswwAQLCItJSwc2WHpDOqBNcMGkDUAZTwQObmcbSIPlFKMlWtLigFjWI4KLqhb5vtoFQF6WaRqqlJJjbrOJrq1tVH9xudrQDiKajuOA2iUXRgYSWURkNLUqXZFRBP@q0QAvCOA08q56o@3vWKp0aabCXw)

The time complexity of the algorithm is \$O(m(m-n)c^2)\$, where \$m\$ and \$n\$ are max and min, and \$c\$ is the count, ignoring the cost of bigint addition (which is not a language built-in, and therefore horribly inefficient). It is nowhere close to the fastest, but it's still much faster than brute-force, as it returns the correct result for `1 10 100 700` in 3 minutes on my PC.

To use, assign the inline operator to `f` and call it in the form of `length (count f) min max`.

```apl
⎕CY'dfns'  ⍝ Load dfns library, so we can use `+big`

{0::0⋄...}  ⍝ If any error occurs, return 0
⍺⊃⍵{...}⍣⍺⍺⊢1  ⍝ Build the vector of all possible combinations by
               ⍝ taking the polynomial represented by ⍵ raised to the power of ⍺⍺,
               ⍝ then fetch the ⍺-th coefficient (might error if ⍺ is out of range)
0,⍣(⊢/⍺)⊢⍵    ⍝ Prepend "max" copies of 0s to the current polynomial
(⍳1+¯1⊥⍺)⌽¨⊂  ⍝ Generate the list of ^ rotated 0..(max-min) times
+big⌿↑        ⍝ Promote to matrix and sum the numbers vertically
```